# Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt

I've a problem building a module into a project with sbt 0.13.5 and scala 2.9.3, I have the dependency defined to

```
"com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.2.3" % "provided"
```

and even when the scalaVersion is explicitly set, throws this error:

```
[error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in {file:/Users/me/Code/project/}module:
[error]    com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala _2.9.2, _2.9.3
```

This is a provided dependency, that works on other module of the same project with the same resolvers and the same explicit scala version, the only difference there is in the additional dependencies, failing project has

```
"bouncycastle" % "bcprov-jdk16" % "140" % "provided",
"com.jolbox" % "bonecp" % "0.7.1.RELEASE" % "provided",
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18" % "provided",
"org.liquibase" % "liquibase-core" % "3.0.5" % "provided",
"org.jdbi" % "jdbi" % "2.51" % "provided",
"javax.mail" % "mail" % "1.4" % "provided",
"com.twitter" % "finagle-redis" % "6.6.2" % "provided",
"com.twitter" % "finatra" % "1.3.9" % "provided"
```

Any idea on how to fix this? It appeared when updated to sbt 0.13, in 0.12 works ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I see what the problem is, finatra 1.3.9 is compiled with scala 2.9.2 and there's a dependency on fasterxml, Tried to fix by cross version mapping but it's a nighmare of dependencies, so, upgrading all dependencies to 2.10 is working so far.